# How to extract only the hour from a timestamp in sql?

Tags: sql, presto

Hi I have data with column name 'trx_time'.

The data looks like this:
'2022-03-06 11:25:36'

I just want to extract the hour from the string. How can I do it?
I was thinking regex_extract. But don't know how to write the regex.

Comment: If the column is a `DATETIME` which it should be, you should be able to just use `SELECT HOUR(trx_time)`, or `SELECT extract(HOUR FROM trx_time)`. Note I have no experience with presto and I am basing this off the documentation here: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html

Answer (score 2):

This will extract the Hour from a date field in Presto.

```
SELECT extract(HOUR FROM trx_time) as hour FROM table_name;
```

However, if your field is a String type representing a timestamp ([ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)), you would have to use the `from_iso8601_date` or `from_iso8601_timestamp` functions.

```
SELECT extract(HOUR FROM from_iso8601_date(trx_time)) as hour FROM table_name;
```